# make result set as table

Tags: sql

**HI,
I want to make the result set as a table to choose from**

```
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT FROM");
```

To make it clear I used the sql server and typed

```
select * from (select column from table) as newtable where newtable.column='someting'
```

this works in the sql server but not in the java

Comment: It's possible, but you'll need to subclass all of the necessary `java.sql` classes in order to replicate their functionality with a datatable stored in memory.

Comment: you should explain your question better, your code is *actually selecting*, but from no table. The `ResultSet` represents the values from a table.

Comment: Dude, java is not responsible for you query. It's SQL. Perhaps, you can tell us about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Create Table**

`CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME AS SELECT * FROM USERS`

**To Create View (Virtual Table)**

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS (SELECT * FROM users);`

**Note :** View is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement

**Update**

I don't think so, it is a matter of `java`. If your query returning some output in `sql server`. Then it will return same value in your java program. Since, java is not responsible for `sql` query. You must be missing required driver/package. You must try some basic query like `select * from user` and check whether, it is showing any output through your java program.

**Try this**

```
select newtable.column,newtable.column1,newtable.column2 from (select * from table) as newtable where newtable.column='someting'
```

If above statement won't work again, then you must have done something wrong in your java code. And it is you, who would be responsible **NOT** java. And,Please **don't blame JAVA**

Comment: it worked in the sql server ,other statements worked on java only this

Comment: can you tell me the error. ?? Since, java provides the facility for handling exception. Then, please let me know, what exception do you getting there

Answer (score 1):

Through below step you can create your result set as table.

```
PreparedStatement st = null;
st = con.prepareStatement("create table newTable select * from table");
st.execute();
```

Comment: is this create a table in the database or it's virtual?

Comment: This will create table based on your database connection property. For Example, If your connection database name is **test** then table created on **test** database. If you want virtual then consider your **resultset rs** as table.

Comment: i want it virtual so that i want to take a result from it not to create a table